# Overwriting a text file in Java

Tags: java, text-files, overwrite, filewriter, bufferedwriter

The application should be able to register a new user and save data to text file which is already has many users' data. This code is works but it doesn't save new data to text file. How should I overwrite the text file? Should I read data from text first and write all the data back to text file or there is a way to just add a new line and write new data there?

```
registerB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            String getFullname = fullnameT.getText();
                            String getUsername = usernameT.getText();
                            String getPassword = passwordT.getText();
                            String getPN = pnT.getText();
                            String getEmail = emailT.getText();
                            boolean theSame = false;
                            String []Fullname = new String[20];
                            String []Username = new String[20];
                            String []Password = new String[20];
                            String []PN = new String[20];
                            String []Email = new String[20];

            if(!getFullname.isEmpty() && !getUsername.isEmpty() && !getPassword.isEmpty() && !getPN.isEmpty() && !getEmail.isEmpty()){
                int k = 0;
                try {
                    Scanner in = new Scanner (new FileReader("login.txt", true));
                    while (in.hasNext()) {
                        Fullname[k] = in.next();
                        Username[k] = in.next();
                        Password[k] = in.next();
                        PN[k] = in.next();
                        Email[k] = in.next();
                        in.next();

                        if(getUsername.equals(Username[k])){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username already has been registered.");
                            theSame = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        k++;
                    }
                }catch(Exception ew){}
                try
                {
                    String path = "login.txt";

                    File file = new File(path);

                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);

                    BufferedWriter bufferFileWriter  = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

                    fileWriter.append("," + getFullname + "," + getUsername + "," + getPassword + "," + getPN + "," + getEmail +"," + "\n");

                    bufferFileWriter.close();

                    System.out.println("User Registration Completed");

                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One or some of the fields is/are empty");
            }
        }
    });
```

The text file format is like this

`fullname,username,password,phonenumber,email`
`fullname,username,password,phonenumber,email`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append text to an existing file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong `new FileReader("login.txt", true)`

[FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) does have this constructor

Change `new FileWriter("login.text")` to `new FileWriter("login.text", true)`

the true will append the new data to the existing data

Comment: I saw it that I didnt include FileWriter. Thnx for ur help